# Вывести переменную, имя которой - элемент массива

Tags: javascript, переменные

Имеется несколько переменных:

```
var 
     one = "cat",
     two = "dog";
```

Далее, есть массив:

```
arr = ["one", "green"];
```

Мне нужно через массив, вывести значение переменной one.

Если сделаю просто console.log(arr[0]); выведет именно значение под этим индексом, нужно вывести "cat".

Описание задачи максимально упростил чтобы не усложнять. 
Если кому-нибудь интересна действительная цель задачи:

Пишу игру, за основы карты взят Canvas.
На клиенте хранятся переменные с изображениями.

```
var left = new Image();
left.src = 'images/left.png';
var right = new Image();
right.src = 'images/right.png';
```

Это спрайты игрока (поворот влево и соответственно вправо).

Когда игрок начинает движение вправо - он отправляет на сервер информацию, часть которой и есть данные о его спрайте, сервер рассылает всем подключенным клиентам новое значение спрайта совместно с другой информацией в виде массива и в конечном итоге на канвасе нужно это отрисовывать.
То есть, сервер отправляет массив данных, в этом массиве есть либо "left", либо "right". Далее нужно вывести изображение исходя со значения.

```
context.drawImage(arr[0], 100, 100, 60, 100);
```

Comment: можно сделать те самые "несколько переменных" в виде объекта, ключ-значение  и потом просто обращаться к нему через квадратные скобки `var obj = {one: 'cat', two: 'dog'};
console.log(obj['one'], obj['two']);`

Comment: здравствуйте, да, тоже думал о таком, но не знаю как добавить в объект такое: var left = new Image();
left.src = 'images/left.png';

Comment: @ЕвгенийКалайда а зачем вы создаете разные переменные? персонаж-то 1? нельзя ли `playerImg.src='images/'+arr[0]+'.png' ` ?

Comment: Потому что изображений несколько может быть, как минимум 4, объявить их нужно в начале, а меняться они будут на протяжении всей игры.